# Let a parabola have a vertex of $T(5,\frac{1}{2})$ and with the x-axes it forms an angle of 45 degrees. Find the point which it traverses?

Tags: calculus, quadratics

I tried to do a lot of stuff to get my answer but always fail. 
$$5 = -\frac{b}{2a} \Rightarrow b=-10a$$
$$\frac{1}{2}= -\frac{-b^2+4ac}{4a} \Rightarrow c=\frac{-49}{8}$$
$$\tan 45=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{x}\Rightarrow x=\frac{1}{2} $$

Therefore I can say that $x_1=5-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{9}{2}$ and $x_x=5+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{11}{2}$

After that I really don't know what my next steps should be. I'm not even sure if these are correct anyway...

[image]

Comment: You mean the x-axis, right?

Comment: The vertex of the parabola forms an angle of 45 deg with the x-axis, right?

Comment: I don't understand? it croses the x axes and it's coefficient is negative, so it looks down..

Comment: Yes it does! That's correct

Comment: Is the parabola horizontal or vertical?

Comment: What does the point of traversal mean?

Comment: Do you mean the equation of the parabola?

Comment: Are you familiar with Linear Algebra?

Comment: Yes the parabola(it's equation but coeeficients are unknown) and we are trying to find another point which it crosses. I have the results .. But don't know which one is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45705/discussion-between-shrey-aryan-and-wesewx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer, I will focus on the cases in which the axis of the parabola is horizontal or vertical. Firstly, I consider the case where the parabola has a vertical axis, i.e. parallel to the $y $-axis. Define the equation of the parabola as $y=ax^2+bx+c $. 
Its derivative $2ax+b \ $ must be zero for $x=5 \ $, so we have $a=-b/10 \  $. Also, since the parabola crosses the vertex  $(5,1/2) \  $, we have $1/2=-b/10 \cdot 5^2 + 5b + c \ $, which leads to $c=\frac {1}{2}- \frac {5}{2} b \ $. So the equation of the parabola can be rewritten as $$y=- \frac {b}{10} x^2 +bx + \frac {1}{2} - \frac {5}{2} b \ $$

Setting $y=0$  we get that the points in which the parabola crosses the $x $-axis are given by the two solutions of the equation $$  -\frac {b}{10} x^2 -\frac {3}{2} bx +1/2=0 \ $$ which are given by $x=5 \pm \sqrt {\frac {5}{b}} \  $. In these points, the derivative $ 2ax+b =-\frac {1}{5} bx+b \ $ must be equal to $\pm 1$ (because the parabola crosses the $x $-axis at $45^o$), so we get the two equations

$$-\frac {b}{5} (5 - \sqrt {\frac {5}{b}} ) +b=1$$
$$-  \frac {b}{5}  (5 +    \sqrt {\frac {5}{b}}    ) +b=-1$$

whose solution is $b=5$ . Then $a=-1/2$ , $c=-12$ , and the equation of the parabola is

$$y=-\frac {1}{2}x^2+5x-12 \ $$

Among the five points provided in the possible answers, only the point $(-2,-24) \ $ is crossed by this parabola.

We can also repeat the same steps for the case where the axis of the parabola is horizontal. The same procedure leads to the following two parabolas:

$$ x=y^2-y+5+1/4$$
$$ x=-y^2+y+5-1/4$$

However, in this case none of the five points provided in the possible answers is crossed by the parabolas. 
Lastly, we have to take into account that other potential solutions might result by considering oblique parabolas. In this case, it is likely that we could obtain multiple solutions, i.e., a set of parabolas that makes different answers (among the five provided) potentially valid.

Comment: I really don't know why you question got voted down... TNX..

Comment: Why the derivative should be 0 at $x=5$ :  *vertex* means horizontal tangent point ? and why crossing the $x$ axis the derivative should be $\pm1$ ? those are the reasons of my downvoting.

Comment: Isn't it because when we do the derivative of a function and equalize it with 0 we get the maximum ant ht maximum really is for x=5?

Comment: yes, but that  is not the vertex of the parabola, i.e. the point of intersection of the parabola with its axis.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I only focused on the cases where the axis of the parabola is vertical or horizontal, and did not assess the possibility of oblique parabolas. Consider that while one of the five possible answers is valid in the case of vertical parabola (as explained in the calculations), none of the answers is valid in the case of horizontal parabola. Also, if we consider the general case of oblique parabola, we are probably left with multiple possible (correct) answers. This is why, in my opinion, who conceived this problem was thinking about a vertical parabola.

Comment: I edited my answer to better explain these issues.

Comment: @Anatoly,  Ok, sorry, the question is actually badly worded,  it should have been specified, especially that $45^\circ$ is the angle at the intersection with the $x$ axis. I deleted my downvote, and transformed in $+$, with compliments for your capability to get through the obscure meaning.